# view.map.loadAll is not a function (Arcgis API for JavaScript)

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I wrote this code (below) to use the Editor widget of Arcgis API for JavaScript,
knowing that before this code I defined my featurelayers (links to shapfiles uploaded on Arcgis server online Arcgis for developers (layers))
by this code I wanted to access all my layers(to edit, add and delete), finally the Editor widget works fine only for a day (I can update my data, delete,add yesterday), but now when I run it, it doesn't work and when I use Insepct element (development tools of google chrome), I find this error in the console:

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: view.map.loadAll is not a function
> at index.html: 410

How to do to get rid of this error message?

```
view.when(() => {
    view.map.loadAll().then(() => {
        view.map.allLayers.forEach((layer) => {
            if (layer.type === "feature") {
                switch (layer.geometryType) {
                    case "polygon":
                        polygonLayer = layer;
                        break;
                    case "polyline":
                        lineLayer = layer;
                        break; 
                    case "point":
                        pointLayer = layer;
                        break;
                }
            }
        })
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "map" property of the view returns a Map, which doesn't have a loadAll method. That method is for a [WebMap](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-WebMap.html#loadAll) instead.

If you want to run the allLayers function when all the layers have loaded, take a look at Rene Rubalcava's blog post "[When are layers done?](https://odoe.net/blog/when-are-layers-done)"

Comment: Thanks  I find the issue and a solution(with help). we don't need to loop trough the layers. The Editor-Widget itself checks the editable layers and add them to the widget , and Sorry for the inconvenience caused